# Reading a CSV file with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, json, csv

I have a downloaded CSV file which I would like to parse and use to create JSON objects for each record. The file is on my local machine but I have read that JavaScript has security measures in place that prevent access to these files.

Some examples show using csv.js with the following:

```
$.ajax({
url: "G:\downloaded_files\filename.csv",
aync: false,
success: function (csvd) {
    csv_as_array = $.csv.toArrays(csvd);
}, 
dataType: "text",
complete: function () {
    // use the array of arrays (variable csv_as_array)
   // for further processing
}
});
```

When running this it just creates a GET request in the console. I am treading on unfamiliar territory here so any explanations would be great.

If I was to do this using Ruby I would do this, which hopefully will give you an indication of what I am trying to achieve:

```
require 'csv'

class FileRead

csv_text = File.read('/home/richardlewis/Downloads/csvtest.csv')
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, headers: true)
  csv.each do |row|
   hash = row.to_hash
   puts(hash)
 end
```

end

I'm hoping this makes sense and someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call local files (from hard dics) using Ajax, or by any means from a web browser. You will have to publish your file using some sort of server. If you are using Linux you should have an Apache server already installed.

You need a REST service that will return your file in some format. JSON is the best, because it's easy to manipulate JSON data on the front-end.

It would look like this:

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://localhost:8080/services/rest/get_file", // your rest address
...
});
```

Comment: You *might* have an Apache server installed, depending on the distribution you're using.